# ¿Cuál sería la traducción al español más aproximada para el "bento" japonés?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término, comida

El *[bentō](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bent%C5%8D)* japonés, además de llegar a ser [pequeñas obras de arte](https://www.google.es/search?q=bento&biw=1366&bih=638&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjsiOHGmNbPAhUMsBQKHYZOBxIQ_AUIBigB), son las comidas que los trabajadores japoneses se llevan a sus lugares de trabajo, y que se pueden comer del tiempo, sin necesidad de calentarlas en microondas. Esto es especialmente útil en puestos de trabajo a la intemperie, como es el caso de los albañiles y demás.

En español, por cortesía de mi mujer que es de Cádiz, he descubierto que tenemos la siguiente palabra:

> **[costo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B7MbcqN)**
>
> De *costar*.
>
> 3. m. Cád. Comida que el peón, albañil, pescador, etc., se lleva hecha para tomarla en el lugar donde trabaja.

Mi mujer recuerda que sus padres usaban mucho esa palabra para designar a esa comida ya preparada. La palabra está recogida en el DRAE, pero se marca como usada solamente en la región de Cádiz. Así que me preguntaba, **¿existe en español una palabra de uso más general que designe a este tipo peculiar de comida para llevar?**

Así a priori se me ocurría *[fiambrera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hq69ddI)*, pero esto designaría más al recipiente donde se llevaría la comida, más que a la comida en sí.

Comment: ¿Que tal [refrigerio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VffXmAU)?

Comment: @DGaleano pues no estoy seguro. Yo refrigerio lo entiendo como [tentempié](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZUM7MgT), algo que se toma por si te da hambre antes de la hora de la comida, para aguantar hasta ésta. Para mí sería un concepto diferente, pero corrígeme si me equivoco, no sea que haya diferencias regionales que desconozca.

Comment: Yo creo que la palabra más adecuada es la que propones, *fiambrera*, que por metonimia ha pasado a denominar también el contenido. Hoy día se usan también *el túper* o *el táper* con el mismo significado.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con Gorpik: _fiambrera_, _túper_ o _táper_, que también corresponden al contenido

Comment: @Gorpik estoy de acuerdo. Desde luego, si alguien pregunta a otro si "le han preparado la fiambrera", no creo que se refieran únicamente al continente, sino más bien al contenido. ¿Te animas a escribir una respuesta?

Comment: De acuerdo, voy a escribirla.

Comment: _Fiambrera_ en Chile es un mueble o escaparate donde se exhiben jamones y quesos. Nadie lo entendería con el sentido de "comida". Aquí a eso le decimos _vianda_ y en el sur _roquín_.

Comment: En Argentina esto sería una *vianda* (como veo que es en Chile). No incluye el recipiente, que puede ser un táper (si uno se lleva un sandwich envuelto en papel film en una bolsa también cuenta como vianda).

Answer (score 8):

Soy una mujer de 61 años, cuando yo era pequeña o muy jovencita mi padre se iba a trabajar, bien fuera turno de día o de noche, mi madre, mi hermana o yo misma, siempre le preparábamos bocadillo de almuerzo o de merienda, envuelto en papel de periódico, no existía el papel film, ni el de aluminio, y la comida o cena en TARTERA metálica de aluminio o acero inoxidable, no existía ni el tuper, taper, de plástico, ni nada por el estilo. Y mi madre siempre decía, " Ya está preparada la tartera y el bocadillo". Ni siquiera existía la palabra bocata. Soy de Valencia.

Comment: Yo soy de México y la palabra **bocadillo** me suena muy natural.

Comment: Manoli, coincido 100% en lo que dices y en tu experiencia: **tartera**, y bocadillo.

Answer (score 7):

Para mí en México (y según la RAE, algunos otros países de Hispanoamérica) eso que describes se llama *lonche*:

> **lonche**  *Del ingl. lunch.*
>
> 1. m. Ec., Guat., Méx., Nic. y Pan. Comida ligera del mediodía.

Comment: ¡Curiosa expresión!

Answer (score 4):

Otra posibilidad podría ser [**merienda**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=P0c4pKa)

> 1. f. Comida ligera que se toma a media tarde.
> 2. f. Comida que se toma **al mediodía**.

Aunque el uso más común sea el de la primera acepción, la segunda se aproxima algo al *bento*.

En [definiciones-de-com](http://www.definiciones-de.com/Definicion/de/merienda.php) incluyen también en "merienda"

> 2. Comida fría que se lleva para irse de excursión o de viaje. Ejemplo: llevarse la merienda en el tren.

Comment: Creo que en este caso, "merienda" en su segunda acepción se usa para designar a una especie de "segundo desayuno". Por ejemplo, la usan en la guardería de mi hijo (como "merendilla") para referirse al desayuno que se llevan para tomar a media mañana. Creo que la acepción en este caso se refiere a una comida pequeña que se toma entre dos más grandes (las cuales no tienen por qué ser el almuerzo y la cena), aunque por supuesto puedo estar equivocado.

Answer (score 4):

En mi opinión, la palabra más adecuada, al menos en España, sería una de las que propone Carlos Alejo en su pregunta: **fiambrera**. Esta palabra, por metonimia, ha pasado a denominar también el contenido de la misma. Es decir: la comida que se lleva dentro preparada para comer en el trabajo, una excursión o lo que sea.

Así, una persona puede decir que se va *a preparar la fiambrera*, o que en el trabajo *come de fiambrera*. En ambos casos se refiere más bien al contenido del recipiente.

En la actualidad es bastante habitual oír las palabras *[túper](https://dle.rae.es/t%C3%BAper)* o *[táper](https://dle.rae.es/t%C3%A1per)* como sinónimos de fiambrera. Estas palabras proceden de la marca comercial [Tupperware](https://www.tupperware.es/), que fabrica recipientes de este tipo. No es raro que se incorporen al idioma palabras derivadas de marcas comerciales; algunos ejemplos que llevan más tiempo recogidos en el diccionario de la RAE son [rímel](https://dle.rae.es/r%C3%ADmel) o [celo](https://dle.rae.es/celo). En cualquier caso, si una persona dice que se va *a hacer el túper para mañana*, se refiere a que va a preparar la comida que luego meterá en su fiambrera.

Answer (score 4):

En México tenemos la palabra **[itacate](https://dle.rae.es/itacate)** que significa provisión.
El itacate se puede llevar al trabajo o a un paseo. También puede ser usado para referir a la comida no consumida que se pide para llevar en un restaurante o que se trae de una fiesta o reunión.

Answer (score 1):

En el suroccidente  colombiano (y según el DAMER, vale para Ecuador, Perú y Bolivia), se puede llevar un *Fiambre*

> Alimento ligero o refrigerio que se toma fuera de casa, generalmente cuando se va de paseo.

Si bien la definición nos manda de paseo, no se impide llevar fiambre para el trabajo, incluso según las respuestas de España, tendría sentido llevar un fiambre en la fiambrera, pero ya es decisión de cada cual

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que yo no he encontrado una palabra específica y siempre le llamo *bento* y la gente se me queda viendo raro hehehe

En Mexico alguna gente le llama *itacate* pero yo solo a las abuelitas he escuchado usar esa palabra. He escuchado que muchos le llaman *lonche*, pero en mi opinión no es lo mismo, creo que es un anglicismo de *lunch*.